# Using 2 Web APIs for one project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am about to start developing a software project that consists of a ASP.NET (Core) website (an MVC project) and later a mobile app version for such a website. I am interested in reusing my code in my Application Layer (Business Objects) and in my Data Layer because they are basically the same for both the website and mobile app. For this I have thought that using Web APIs is the solution to **code reuse and a loosely coupled design**. However, I wonder if building a Web API for Data Layer and for Application Layer makes sense as shown below:

[image]

I have found very very few articles on the web that talk about this scenario and I would like to get more feedback. What I have seen is the Application Layer implemented using a class library but in this way it seems to me that it would be "attached" to the website and to the mobile app independently. So, if I make modifications to it, then I need to address 2 different places; I mean to "recompile" and replace in 2 different places.

As a Web API newbie, I ask you to please provide feedback on this subject.

The link below, for example, talk about multiple Web APIs and mentions that "Large companies like YouTube, Google and GitHub use a single API for everything - GET requests, POST requests, Authentication, etc."

[Using multiple Web APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69152859/is-it-worth-to-use-two-separate-api-servers-for-authentication-and-other-general#:%7E:text=Large%20companies%20like%20YouTube%2C%20Google,each%20of%20those%20services%20differently.)

Respectfully,
Jorge Maldonado

Comment: a web API is part of the application layer, I'm not sure if it good to use web api as data layer. But if you want to achieve `code reuse and a loosely coupled design`, You can refer to onion architecture.